# Gibberish from ReadFile()?

Tags: c++, readfile, tchar

I have redirected the stdout of java.exe using pipe. Now I read the output using ReadFile and char buffer:

```
ReadFile( childStdOUTRd, buffer, sizeof(char) * 4096, &read, NULL);
```

The buffer will be assigned correct data. But if I change it to TCAHR[4096]:

```
ReadFile( childStdOUTRd, buffer, sizeof(TCHAR) * 4096, &read, NULL);
```

The buffer received gibberish. Do I miss something ?

Comment: How are you deciding that the buffer received "gibberish"?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Those are words can not be read.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly It is wchar_t.

Comment: @zzy how are you trying to read them?  Can you show the code you use to read them.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is same to https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx , just change the buffer to tchar and child process is java.exe (run a .jar game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should check the return value of `ReadFile`. If it returned `FALSE` then the read failed and the data might be gibberish.

Also, check the value of `read`. It will say how many characters were read.  Don't try to work with anything in the buffer beyond the value of `read` bytes.

Next, the `ReadFile` function receives raw bytes, it does not interpret them.  If your system has `TCHAR` defined as a 16-bit `wchar_t`,  then this call will read `8192` bytes from the input stream.  It should work correctly.

You didn't say how you determined that the buffer received "gibberish".  If you are trying to pretend that the buffer contains actual `wchar_t`s but the input stream did not contain `wchar_t`s then it will not make sense. The solution to this is: Don't Do That.

Finally, `TCHAR` has not been relevant for the last 15 years. Use either `char` or `wchar_t` according to your needs.

Comment: It seems the output of child process can not be transferred to `TCHAR`.